# Authenticate user against asp.net forms Authentication in Chrome Extesnion

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, forms-authentication

I am creating a chrome extension that requires some services implemented by asp.net. I want to authenticate the user against asp.net forms auth from withing the extension. I have searched on google but most of the [articles](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) describe authentication from extension for Oauth providers (google, facebook etc.). In my scenario what are my options and what are the best practices for authenticating user against my website in chrome extension. My application is a Browser action BTW, if it matters.

**Edit:** In my website user can login with multiple accounts but at one time only one account is active. Currently, i am polling the web service to see if a user is online or not but if user switches from one account to another, i have no way of tracking this. I have not found a single example of chrome extension authentication against asp.net web forms. Can anyone guide me what is best (standard) option for authenticating extension request against asp.net forms auth?

Comment: So the extension talks to one website that uses forms auth?

Comment: yes it only talks to one website and we have luxury to provide functionality at server side if its required for implementation of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this response from another post ... if i can help ^^

If you add your site to "Local Intranet" in

Chrome > Options > Under the Hood > Change Proxy Settings > Security (tab) > Local Intranet/Sites > Advanced.

Add you site URL here and it will work.
link|edit

answered Oct 18 '11 at 21:10
daveomcd
567317